# Instrumentation amplifier and sensor

Tags: power-electronics

Why do we use instrumentation amplifier for many sensor based application ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is is completely ambiguous.  There are **several** different temperature sensors.  Which one(s) are you asking about?

Comment: He's asking about the amplifier, not the sensor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't.  An instrumentation amplifier is just an amplifier like an opamp, but with much higher accuracy and gain.  By itself it cannot measure anything.  It often is used as an interface for sensors that produce a low signal level: strain gauges, inductive pickups, medical sensors (EEG, EKG, etc.) and some temperature sensors.